# What is the name of the manga when mc doesn't have an element (power) yet and when party faces tough enemy he is left behind, but friend stays too?

Tags: story-identification, manga

When the friend stays behind with the abandoned mc she fights the monster for a little while and when in danger mc finally gets his power and awakens I think all elements and uses lightning with sword to defeat the monster and they get back and inform the guild.(early chapters)

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: mostly black & white